# Knitting to pdf fails to show axis values and labels in the plot

Tags: r, pdf, plot, knitr, r-markdown

When knitting to pdf in R Markdown, the plot in the pdf file doesn’t contain axis values and labels. 
[image]

However, they are printed correctly in the plot inline. 
[image]
(Acturally knitting to html and word works, too)

Any idea about why knitting to pdf fails to show axis values and labels in the plot and how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is the font.

Comment: The problem came from my .Rpfofile, where I changed font settings. After deleting it, knitting to pdf successfully yields plots with axis values and labels. Thank you for your time!